# In ruby, how can I remove non word characters?

Tags: ruby, regex, rexml

this script is a part of a bigger one, when I run this script I get "`<p></p>`" print out as well. How can I remove this?

I used this regex:  `m.gsub!(/(?=\S)(\d|\W)/,"")`

But it only removed the char "<" and "/>"

**Here is my script:**

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

doc = REXML::Document.new(open('http://testnavet.skolverket.se/SusaNavExport/EmilObjectExporter?id=184594606&amp;strId=info.uh.gu.GS5&amp;EMILVersion=1.1').read)

doc.elements.each("//*[name()='ct:text'] | /ns:educationInfo/ns:extensionInfo/gu:guInfoExtensions/gu:guSubject/gu:descriptions/gu:description"){
          |e| m = e.text 
              puts "Description: " + m  
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the value between `<p></p>` tag?

Comment: What do you define a "word" as? What you have *is* removing non-word characters. `p` is a word character so it remains.

Comment: I like to remove the html char, @AndrewMarshall yeah I know buddy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so you want to remove HTML tags. If so, you can do this:

```
str.gsub(/<.+?>/, "")
```

Thus, "<div>Hello world!</div>" becomes "Hello world"

Comment: **No, it doesn’t.**  It becomes `""`.

Comment: That's because it should be:  `/<.+?>/`  where you do the non-greedy match:  `+?`.  Note, this is a base-case and escaped > characters would defeat this.  Is that what the OP is looking for?

Comment: just for those who dont know http://rubular.com/ is a great place for playing around with ruby regexps

Comment: it should be: str.gsub!(/<.+?>/, "")... you forgat the the "!" char

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake Note that `gsub` does work, it just returns the result, rather than modifying `str` like `gsub!` does.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Aha, cool. Do you know how I should handle the outputs that dosent have anything in them?

Comment: That just means there was nothing inside the tag